# Intellij random errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a few problems with IntelliJ since a few days now. He keeps giving me errors while they aren't really errors, my program runs fine and the errors are always the same. Mostly it's `println`, `Override`, `LocalDate`, `Scanner` and more.

How do I resolve this problem? Every time I open a new project he will do the same.

[image: http://prntscr.com/5pjlog]

[image: http://prntscr.com/5pjlw3]

Comment: Have you defined a JDK for your Project??

Comment: @vikingsteve Good to know if he did that, but wouldn't IntelliJ also complain about every keyword/class (e.g. `String` and `System`)?

Comment: what are the errors ?By underlining,maybe the IDE is just giving a notice about something, that doesn't automatically mean it's an error.

Comment: Yes I added a JDK to my projects, well i think i did... if I go to project structure it mentions the JDK directory I made.

Comment: The errors are: "Cannot resolve Symbol" and "Cannot resolve method"

Comment: Weird. did you define the wrong JDK? which one is it?

Comment: @vikingsteve 1.8.0_20

Comment: Clear caches, Restart intellij, does that help?

Comment: @vikingsteve Wow that seemed to have helped :D Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is tangled here. Since you verified the SDK is set up correctly, can I suggest to just clear caches and Restart intellij.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Project SDK, since you are using Java8 classes, set the ProjectSDK and language to Java 8. [image]

Comment: @Rockett Can you make sure that under ProjectStructure->Modules->Sources->LanguageLevel you have selected `UseProjectLanguageLevel` ?

Comment: @sol4me Yes it is selected like that

Comment: @Rockett Under ProjectStructure->Modules->Dependencies , `Project SDK` is selected?

Comment: @sol4me Yes, maybe i could add that the errors started popping up since i copied a code from someone, ever since then all the errors started to pop up

Comment: @Rockett Can you make sure that under `PlatformSettings->SDKs->NAME_OF_YOUR_SDK->Classpath` is pointing to valid jars ?